# Is the 'way atoms spin' mentioned in the article "Physicists observe 'negative mass'" the same thing as quantum spin?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, mass, quantum-spin, bose-einstein-condensate

The BBC News article [*Physicists observe 'negative mass'*](http://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-39642992) talks about a recent observation of negative effective mass in a BEC gas; in its description of the experiment the article writes

> To create the conditions for negative mass, the researchers used lasers to trap the rubidium atoms and to kick them back and forth, changing the way they spin.

Is the 'spin' mentioned in that sentence the same thing as the [spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)) generally known from particles?

Comment: Please change the title of this question to one that actually describes your query.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I'd be thankful if you could make an appropriate proposal.

Comment: I've edited in a proposal; obviously feel free to roll back if you're unhappy with it.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thank you. That's fine for me. Though it's a bit more than just the title. May I now also upvote since the question is more yours than mine now? ;)

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_mass  this is not mainstream physics , " It is used in certain speculative theories,"

Comment: @annav I wasn't aware of that. Does that mean _BBC News, Science & Environment_ is not a reputable source and "[Prof Peter Engels](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peter_Engels), from Washington State University (WSU), and colleagues" are, well, what then? On the other hand, WP isn't really quotable, AFAIK.

Comment: "non mainstream" is not synonymos with "not reputable". Mainstream physics means physics that is taught in university courses . the paper is peer reviewed so it has passed the first step but it is still in the realm of research and needs new, non standard, theoretical models.

Comment: see the answers to this question https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44934/does-matter-with-negative-mass-exist

Comment: @annav Dear Anna, can it be that there's something in my comment that can be misunderstood? I'm not a native English speaker, so that can happen on occasion. With "not a reputable source" I intended to refer to _BBC News ..._ (and to WP, for that matter, though my wording was "not quotable" in this respect) not to "non mainstream" physics, physicists, research they perform, papers they produce and models they develop, may they be non-standard, theoretical or whatever. With kind regards,

Comment: Dear Anna, thank you very much for the link. Apparently the page it links to contains a lot of valuable information, even high-level knowledge. Apart from that the only circumstance worth mentioning is the fact that it doesn't contain a single occurrence of the word "spin". With kind regards,

Comment: @GeroldBroser Thought it might just be useful to give a link to another question on the same news: _[Negative mass, or just the 'appearance'? What's the acid test?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/327450/139130)_. Although the [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/327455/139130) there doesn't speak of _spin_ in particular, it does indeed address the core issue: _["Once you push, it accelerates backwards"](https://phys.org/news/2017-04-physicists-negative-mass.html)_ (in the article, immediately after referencing "spin"). In that sense, I guess, _spin_ shouldn't mean _quantum spin_

Comment: @DhruvSaxena Thank you for linking this other question here. Re "I guess, _spin_ shouldn't mean _quantum spin_" – That's most probably a very good guess (BTW, it was and still is mine, too) but I'm a SW developer for a living since decades. I have to be exact there and this is one of the reasons why I like it. Hence I like to know things for sure, without having to guess about them. That's why I was asking about this particular term here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer to this question is that the "spin" referred to is quantum spin.

A longer answer involves describing the superfluid Bose-Einstein Condensate experimental technique. One technical paper (from 2011) describing a form of the method is [Spin-Orbit-Coupled-Bose-Einstein Condensates](http://ws680.nist.gov/publication/get_pdf.cfm?pub_id=907073).

The relevant aspect to your question is that Rubidium atoms (in a [Bose-Einstein Condensate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bose%E2%80%93Einstein_condensate)) have two quantum spin states selected (by an experimental technique), say |up> and |down>. The momentum of the components is determined by the particle's mass and by a "spin-orbit coupling". This generates a "pseudo-momentum" and associated "effective mass" - in short the component's (pseudo-)momentum is determined not only by its mass and velocity but also by its spin state. This coupling strength is controllable by lasers, so that pseudo-momentum can vary by manipulating laser strengths.

An added complication is that the behaviour of the BEC is described not directly by the Schrodinger equation, but by a non-linear approximation called the [Gross-Pitaevksii Equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gross%E2%80%93Pitaevskii_equation).

This non-linear equation can have unusual solutions like solitons.

Overall a synthetic quantum environment has been created (in the superfluid) in which one can apparently simulate: negative mass, Galilean non-covariance, and other unusual dynamical pseudo-properties.