# Is it possible to use Bose-Einstein condensate for propulsion with today's tech?

Tags: rocket-science, bose-einstein-condensate, propulsion

Can one use the Bose Einstein condensate which we can produce today for space propulsion, as many theoretical concepts need negative mass and that is a property of Bose Einstein condensate, how feasible is this with today's tech if at all how far are we away?(p.s throwing it out the back isn't allowed)I'm talking about feasibility not if it's physically possible.....

Comment: You should include your source for the statement "Bose einstein condensates have negative mass," as you are almost certainly misunderstanding what it says (which might be the fault of the writer).

Comment: A BEC can have negative *effective* mass. That's quite different to exotic matter with genuine negative mass. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/327450/negative-mass-or-just-the-appearance-of-negative-mass-whats-the-acid-test Also, https://www.universetoday.com/135158/team-creates-negative-effective-mass-lab/

Comment: Oh thank you for clarifying